# MySQL filter/find common value in column

Tags: mysql, database

```
Borrower_id    Branch_id
7                 1
8                 1
8                 2
9                 1
9                 2
```

With the table above, I am trying to find a query that gives me the common `branch_id` for `borrower_id` values. I do not know the values of `branch_id` but I know that the numbers 7, 8 and 9 have the value `1` as common values whereas the numbers 8 and 9 have the common value `2` (which I don't want to select because 7 has to be included, again, because of the common value `1`).

**This is the expected output :**

```
Borrower_id    Branch_id
7                 1
8                 1
9                 1
```

Is there a way I can achieve this? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE branch_id=1?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Tested with you current set of data but need to be tested in different scenarios you have.

```
SELECT a.* FROM your_table a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT branch_id, COUNT(branch_id) cnt
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY branch_id
    HAVING cnt = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT borrower_id) FROM your_table)
) b ON b.branch_id = a.branch_id
```